# Assign new column values based on previous rows from the same column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe with columns : A, B, C containing float values.
I'm trying to assign a new column D. The second row of D is calculated using the first row of A,B.
Then I need to use the second row of D to calculate the third row and so on.

That's my code for assigning the new column.
Using this code I got error: KeyError: 'D'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {
  "A": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
  "B": [15, 25, 35, 45, 55],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def newdf(df):
    return(df
            [['A', 'B']]
            .assign(C = df['B'] + 2,
             D = lambda x : np.where(df.index == 1, round(((x['A'].shift(1) + x['B'].shift(1))/2),2), round(((x['C'].shift(1) + x['D'].shift(1))/2),2))
        )
)
df = newdf(df)
print(df)
```

I don't want to use for loops.

Comment: You are referring to `D` while this column doesn't exist yet. Please provide a [mre] to clarify (input + expected output) and explain the logic

Comment: Try to first create the column 'D' : `df['D'] = np.nan`

Comment: @AchilleG that probably won't give the expected output, OP should really clarify the logic. Most likely `np.where` should **not** be used

Comment: I can't use the same column twice in the assign function: SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: D

Comment: @Pythonic please provide the final expected output, what you want is really unclear

Comment: I need to assign the second row of D using the first row of A,B then every next row is calculated using the previous row of C,D

Comment: @Pythonic what is your exact desired output? can you add your output in code of dataframe or text table?

Comment: @Pythonic please be explicit, provide a manually crafted output with the exact numbers given your example input

Comment: "A": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
  "B": [15, 25, 35, 45, 55],
  "C": [17, 27, 37, 47, 57],
  "D": [nan, 22.5, 24.25, 31.12, 39.06]

Comment: To achieve what you're trying to do, which is essentially a recursive calculation, you can't use vectorized operations because each operation depends on the previous result. Normally, a loop would be the go-to solution. But, since you mentioned that you want to avoid loops, you can try to use ```expanding``` method, but it also has limitations and might not fit this recursive requirement.

Comment: D must be [nan, 12.5, 19.75, 28.38, 37.69] *

Comment: I am not quite understanding the logic for getting D. Could you explain how you are getting [nan, 12.5, 19.75, 28.38, 37.69]. Or just explain how you get the 12.5 please in terms of simple maths.

Comment: D[1] = (A[0] + B[0] ) / 2 #  (10 + 15) / 2 = 12.5
D[2] = (C[1] + D[1]) / 2 # (27 + 12.5) / 2 = 19.75
D[3] = (C[2] + D[2]) / 2 # (37 + 19.75) / 2 = 28.375
and so on..
D[0] is nan because we don't have A[-1] and B[-1]

Answer (score 2):

You best approach is most likely a loop.

What you want to compute is:

```
                            NaN 
                     (10+15)/ 2
              27/2 + (10+15)/ 4
       37/2 + 27/4 + (10+15)/ 8
47/2 + 37/4 + 27/8 + (10+15)/16
```

You could broadcast using a square matrix of the factors:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.r_[df.loc[0, ['A', 'B']].sum(), df['C'].to_numpy()[1:-1]]

idx = np.arange(len(a))
m = idx[:,None]-idx+1
df.loc[1:, 'D'] = np.nansum(a / 2**np.where(m>0, m, np.nan), axis=1)
```

But this will create a NxN intermediate, which will require a lot of memory.

This should however be fast with a loop and `numba`:

```
from numba import jit

a = np.r_[df.loc[0, ['A', 'B']].mean(), df['C'].to_numpy()[1:]]

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(arr):
    out = [np.nan]
    prev = arr[0]
    for val in arr[:-1]:
        prev = (prev+val)/2
        out.append(prev)
    return out

df['D'] = f(a)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C        D
0  10  15  17      NaN
1  20  25  27  12.5000
2  30  35  37  19.7500
3  40  45  47  28.3750
4  50  55  57  37.6875
```

##### timings

Comparison of Onyambu's vectorized approach and the numba loop. Numba is reliably faster (~70%) since it performs less operations. Building the logic is also more straightforward.

[image]

Comment: This is easily vectorizable. I believe. No need of creating N * N intermediate matrix. Just simple math will do it

Comment: @Onyambu that's right, yet the loop with numba is still faster (since it does less computations). I'm adding a comparison in my answer. Sometimes loops are faster, especially when combined with numba ;)

Answer (score 1):

The task you have is multiplication and therefore it is easily vectorizable. Using the idea from @mozway above, we could do:

```
df['C'] = df['B'] + 2
b = pd.Series([df['B'].iloc[0], *df['C'].iloc[1:]])
c = 2 ** b.index

df['D'] = (df['A'].iloc[0] + (b * c).cumsum()) / (c * 2)
    A   B   C         D
0  10  15  17  12.50000
1  20  25  27  19.75000
2  30  35  37  28.37500
3  40  45  47  37.68750
4  50  55  57  47.34375
```

To get the `NaN` as mozways shows, just shift the D column by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use the D column in the formula where you calculate D, you should define it beforehand. You can simply continue as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
  "A": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
  "B": [15, 25, 35, 45, 55],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['C'] = np.nan #optional
df['D'] = np.nan
```